Re-insulating wall from interior after water leak
There was water damage caused by an A/C unit that rested inside of a window which leaked across the inside of the wall. The tenant complained about cold drafts, I figured the insulation around the window and the black vapor/tar barrier (I don't know what this material is or what name it has, the house was built in 1960's) got damaged.
I don't know what appropriate fix to prevent drafts and potentially improve the comfort inside the room. I considered trying to replace the black barrier that crumbles to the touch with something like homewrap and blue sheating tape (if I can slip it behind the framing, I am not considered replacing the window at this time). Is there anything else I can do to insulate the wall? Looking for an assembly that has some ventilation to prevent condensation.
I'm open to more extensive repairs if short-term repairs are not applicable, or at least get an idea of what it would entail.
Live in the northern hemisphere(Quebec(Canada)). Room is situated on the 2nd floor (it's a row house, this wall happens to be facing the outside).



The northern hemisphere is literally half the planet. A bit more precision with respect to latitude would be appreciated.

It's a bit of a whack-a-mole game to try and stop airflow from inside, especially with a local repair like this. The drywall you will put up blocks airflow in the bulk of the wall, so you're mostly concerned with penetrations like electrical boxes and windows. Seal them up as best you can and leave any real repairs for the next time you side the house. Then you'll add house wrap, window flashing tape, etc. To truly deal with the issue in a modern fashion.
